# Android Studio gradle wrong version during build

Tags: android, gradle

When I do `.\gradlew --version` in Android Studio powershell, I get correct version (6.7.1). But when I build project I get errors related to com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0. In "Project Structure" it correctly it shows 6.7.1. In "Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle" it uses gradle from gradle-wrapper.properties file which correctly links 6.7.1.

EDIT: If this is about Android Gradle Plugin Version, it correctly references 4.2.2 everywhere I checked

EDIT: I also don"t understand why it logs org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32 in error I have org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10 referenced in build.gradle

These are the build errors:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-app-all'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':sample-app-all:classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0 > com.android.tools:common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.0
   > Could not find commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.1/asm-analysis-9.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.1/asm-analysis-9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.1/asm-commons-9.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.1/asm-commons-9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-util:9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.1/asm-util-9.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.1/asm-util-9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
   > Could not find net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
   > Could not find com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javapoet/1.10.0/javapoet-1.10.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.10.0/javapoet-1.10.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.1.0-7984345
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
   > Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.1.0
   > Could not find io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.21.1/grpc-core-1.21.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.21.1/grpc-core-1.21.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
   > Could not find io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.21.1/grpc-netty-1.21.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.21.1/grpc-netty-1.21.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
   > Could not find io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.21.1/grpc-protobuf-1.21.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.21.1/grpc-protobuf-1.21.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
   > Could not find io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.21.1/grpc-stub-1.21.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.21.1/grpc-stub-1.21.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-core:1.4.32.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-core/1.4.32/dokka-core-1.4.32.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-core/1.4.32/dokka-core-1.4.32.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/flatbuffers/flatbuffers-java/1.12.0/flatbuffers-java-1.12.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/flatbuffers/flatbuffers-java/1.12.0/flatbuffers-java-1.12.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc2/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc2.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc2/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc2.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0 > com.android.tools:common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.4.32/kotlin-reflect-1.4.32.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.4.32/kotlin-reflect-1.4.32.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
   > Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
   > Could not find net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/intellij/deps/trove4j/1.0.20181211/trove4j-1.0.20181211.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/intellij/deps/trove4j/1.0.20181211/trove4j-1.0.20181211.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
   > Could not find xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.0/xercesImpl-2.12.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.0/xercesImpl-2.12.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.0
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.0
   > Could not find com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:30.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.0
   > Could not find net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.6.0/jna-platform-5.6.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.6.0/jna-platform-5.6.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.0
   > Could not find org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
   > Could not find com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.0
   > Could not find org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.1.0
   > Could not find com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.2/auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.2/auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
   > Could not find com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.1/error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.1/error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
   > Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/dagger/dagger/2.28.3/dagger-2.28.3.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/dagger/dagger/2.28.3/dagger-2.28.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
   > Could not find org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bitbucket/b_c/jose4j/0.7.0/jose4j-0.7.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/bitbucket/b_c/jose4j/0.7.0/jose4j-0.7.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
   > Could not find org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0
   > Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.60/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.60.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.60/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.60.pom
     Required by:
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09
         project :sample-app-all > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom
       - ...

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: @GowthamKK Just did

Comment: Ithink the problem not related to the gradle version but you have to add         mavenCentral()

Comment: Has mavenCentral() in buildscript.repositories

Comment: In settings.gradle also?

Comment: No settings.gradle only has include and project statements

Answer (score 0):

Error is coming from Android studio gradle plugin version.
You can find plugin version project level gradle file

```
build.gradle

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
```

This plugin is a tool to integrate gradle into android studio.
Gradle is separate build tool.

Your gradle version is not compatable with plugin version. You need to update gradle version found in gradle-wrapper.properties.

You can update [gradle version](https://gradle.org/releases/). Please check [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility-7-1-0) for plugin version with compatible gradle versions.

Comment: I do see `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"` in build.gradle which is compatible with my gradle version I don't know why it seems to use com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0

Comment: Your versions are quite outdated. You can update plugin to latest version 7.2.0 in gradle file and gradle version to 7.5.1 latest version in wrapper.properties . Other sdk tools are also depends on these version. So you can make them updated to latest

Comment: Yea it's not my project I'm just trying to run it and learn I must say it's the first time I am building native android project.

Answer (score 0):

In 'build.gradle' I changed my version from 4.2.2 to 3.5.3 and it worked correctly.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
  }
}
```

PD: I am from Chile, if I made a mistake in my English you can correct it.